# Why does the copy constructor (of a C++ class) get called when a function returns?

Tags: c++, class, oop, copy-constructor

Here is a fragment of a program:

```
cls fun(cls a)
{
     cls v;
     v = a.scale(2.0);
     return v;
}
int main()
{
     cls a(0.0,1.0,2.0);
     cls a2;
     a2 = fun(a);
     return 0;
}
```

In the above code assume that the class definition of the class "cls" has the constructor function and the "scale" function already defined. My doubt is in the main function we have instantiated the object a2 and after that we are assigning it to the return value of the function. So, why will the copy constructor get called in this case? (I am following some resource to understand the OOP using C++ and it is mentioned over there that in the above case the copy constructor gets called.)

Also, in the above code if I write:

```
cls a2 = fun(a);
```

Then, from my understanding, the copy constructor must be called (because we are instantiating a2 as a copy of something). Now, the **fun(a)** returns a temporary object, but the parameter of the copy constructor function takes a reference value since we cannot take the reference value of a temporary object, shouldn't this give an error?

Comment: Are you sure that here `a2 = fun(a);` the copy constructor will be called? Isn't it a case for assignment operator call?

Comment: @vahancho: OP is aware of that: see the text starting with "Also,"

Comment: Loosly speaking the copy constructor must be called because fun returns a temporary. The result must be copied from the stackframe of the function into a2. The stackframe of the function is kept alive by the compiler for the duration of the copy constructor. Think of it as running as the last think inside the function, not the first thing after the function. So the reference to the temporary is still valid. Note: Newer c++ compilers will eliminate the copy constructor. It gets `elided`. The standard defines when this may happen and it avoids most cases of useless copying like in your case.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow and "when this may" is becoming "when this must".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler generated copy constructor takes a `const` reference as the parameter.

An anonymous temporary is allowed to bind to a `const` reference, so compilation passes.

Note that the implied value copy created by `return v;` is *elided* in later C++ standards.

Comment: I could not understand this: "....impllied value copy created by return v;..." in your answer. Could you please explain what you meant? Did you mean - some sort of copying takes place when 'return v;" is executed (hence the copy constructor gets called) and that copied value is assigned to a2 (since only assigning is taking place in this step, the copy constructor won't get called.)  Is this what you meant? Thank you!

Comment: @AdityaS: That's exactly it. Early compilers would take a value copy for `return v;`. Google NRVO for more on this.